# Can the real-time Green's function be written in the form of path integral on the real axis?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, path-integral, greens-functions

In every textbook, the path integral of the Green's function is written in imaginary-time. I wonder whether we could write real-time green function in the path integral form.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the (equilibrium) statistical mechanics textbooks, which deal mainly with the statistical sum, and therefore need only the imaginary path integral.

The real-time path integral is usually derived in quantum mechanics textbooks, where it is sometimes also shown to be the direct solution of the Schrödinger equation with a source term, i.e. a true Green's function in the mathematical sense. Feymann's own QM book is probably a good place to look.

Finally, non-equilibrium statistical mechanics routinely uses Green's functions in real time. For the path integral formulation of the Keldysh formalism you may look [here](http://www.capri-school.eu/capri09/lectures/Kamenev_Capri09.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

PS: I notice that if we can distort the time integral line (to include imaginary part), then it is possible to establish the path integral formulation of real-time green function (at least for fermions). So I edited my question so that the time integral has to be defined on real axis.

—————

All right after discussing with professor, I’ll answer the question myself.
The crucial point is that the real-time green function is defined on zero temperature, so the contribution to the two point function will only come from the ground state, and the factor $e^{-\beta H}$ will be thrown away. As a result, the remaining time ordered operator will appear as some evolution operators not in a time ordered place. (Without considering time contour as in @Vadim answer or other more complicated situations) So it can not be written as a path integral.